# UISplitViewController with UITabBarController inside the MasterViewController in Universal App

Tags: swift, ios8, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

[Picture of my storyboard, i use a login screen first and then the splitview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB4IB.png)I'm embedding a TabBarController into a MasterView in a SplitView for an Universal App, the thing is that it works perfectly when it's being used in an iPad or iPhone 6 plus (landscape) but when it's in an iPhone or using the new multitasking in the iPad and set to half of the screen, everytime I want to show the DetailViewController, it pops up instead of being pushed as a normal ViewController inside its NavigationController. I thought I had already solved it months ago but now with the iOS 9 update it fails again.

I think it has something to do with the function:

`func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, showDetailViewController vc: UIViewController, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool`

but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: If you're using storyboards please show image of storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting your view structure is incorrect, just that I would not build it in a storyboard in that way. So my suggestion is that you try the following as an alternative...

If you do, make sure you duplicate your storyboard and make the changes in the duplicate. This way, if my suggested changes do not work, you will be able to delete the duplicate test storyboard and revert to the original.

The idea is to swap your primary view controllers around...

I'm not certain how the login view works with the remainder of the storyboard so I guess that is instantiated as "Initial view controller"?

Regardless... looking at your storyboard, you do not require split view controllers for all the views, only your "Home" and "Detail" views.

So make the tab bar controller the first view (after the "Login" view).

Set / drag a connection from the tab controller to each of the following:

- navigation controller for "Advanced Search";
- navigation controller for "Repositiories";
- a split view controller.

From the split view controller, drag:

- a master view connection to "Home" navigation controller; and
- a detail view connection to "Detail" navigation controller.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but that wouldn't help me. Most of the views are connected to the Detail and also i don't want t a general tabBar in the application, just one inside the master. Everything works perfect but the problem is when the app goes into Compact mode (iPhones), it doesn't reassignate the view stack so the navigation is broken.